# What does >= means in this context

Tags: c++, opencv

I'm trying to understand code that makes use of OpenCV library to identify squares on any given image. There's this line towards the end - "gray = gray0 >= (l + 1) * 255 / N;". I have never seen >= used in that way and it doesn't look like it's doing comparison. What does that operator do in that line?

```
static void findSquares(const Mat& image, vector<vector<Point> >& squares)
{
Mat pyr, timg, gray0(image.size(), CV_8U), gray;

pyrDown(image, pyr, Size(image.cols / 2, image.rows / 2));
pyrUp(pyr, timg, image.size());
vector<vector<Point> > contours;

for (int c = 0; c < 3; c++)
{
    int ch[] = { c, 0 };
    mixChannels(&timg, 1, &gray0, 1, ch, 1);

    // try several threshold levels
    for (int l = 0; l < N; l++)
    {
        // hack: use Canny instead of zero threshold level.
        // Canny helps to catch squares with gradient shading
        if (l == 0)
        {
            // apply Canny. Take the upper threshold from slider
            // and set the lower to 0 (which forces edges merging)
            Canny(gray0, gray, 0, thresh, 5);
            // dilate canny output to remove potential
            // holes between edge segments
            dilate(gray, gray, Mat(), Point(-1, -1));
        }
        else
        {
            // apply threshold if l!=0:
            //     tgray(x,y) = gray(x,y) < (l+1)*255/N ? 255 : 0
            gray = gray0 >= (l + 1) * 255 / N;
        }
 .....
```

Updated

```
        // find contours and store them all as a list
        findContours(gray, contours, RETR_LIST, CHAIN_APPROX_SIMPLE);

        vector<Point> approx;

        // test each contour
        for (size_t i = 0; i < contours.size(); i++)
        {
            // approximate contour with accuracy proportional
            // to the contour perimeter
            approxPolyDP(Mat(contours[i]), approx, arcLength(Mat(contours[i]), true)*0.02, true);

            // square contours should have 4 vertices after approximation
            // relatively large area (to filter out noisy contours)
            // and be convex.
            // Note: absolute value of an area is used because
            // area may be positive or negative - in accordance with the
            // contour orientation
            if (approx.size() == 4 &&
                fabs(contourArea(Mat(approx))) > 1000 &&
                isContourConvex(Mat(approx)))
            {
                double maxCosine = 0;

                for (int j = 2; j < 5; j++)
                {
                    // find the maximum cosine of the angle between joint edges
                    double cosine = fabs(angle(approx[j % 4], approx[j - 2], approx[j - 1]));
                    maxCosine = MAX(maxCosine, cosine);
                }

                // if cosines of all angles are small
                // (all angles are ~90 degree) then write quandrange
                // vertices to resultant sequence
                if (maxCosine < 0.3)
                    squares.push_back(approx);
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: `>=` is the same old comparison operator (technically a *relational operator*), however you are using it on a `Mat` therefore you are invoking an overloaded operator. This is just the same as a function whose name is `operator>=` and it could return anything really, we can't tell just from this code. Consult the class definition of `Mat` to see what it says about its overloaded operators.  It's conventional for overloaded relational operators to return `bool` so that they behave similarly to the built-in operators ; but this is not a strict requirement

Comment: I have to agree with @M.M . The code snippet you have provided and in particular this assignment looks weird to say the least. 1) the expression returns boolean but `gray` is `cv::Mat` and 2) the expression itself looks incorrect. You cannot use `>=` just like that between a `cv::Mat` (here `gray0`) and a number (`(l + 1) * 255/N)` is a number).

Comment: There is some thread-bare documentation [here](http://docs.opencv.org/2.4/modules/core/doc/basic_structures.html#matrixexpressions)

Comment: gray being of Mat type confuses me. That's when I realize the expression does not return boolean.  And the rest of the code doesn't really that helpful to understand that line. But I updated anyway in case it's helpful

Comment: I think @oklas has the answer though it needs a little bit formatting. :D

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Based on the OpenCV [documentation on `cv::Mat`](http://docs.opencv.org/2.4/modules/core/doc/basic_structures.html#matrix-expressions) this expression returns a channel mask (a `cv::Mat`) which is then assigned to gray (another `cv::Mat`):

> Comparison: `A cmpop B, A cmpop alpha, alpha cmpop A`, where `cmpop` is
>   one of :  `>, >=, ==, !=, <=, <`. The result of comparison is an **8-bit
>   single channel mask** whose elements are set to 255 (if the particular
>   element or pair of elements satisfy the condition) or 0.

Comment: Yes, I have add the link with ancor. But currently I have no found source line with  this. It is possible defined as non class methods, and there is no such methods in class but as external function somewhere.

Comment: Yes it is most likely to be a non-member function

Comment: Fascinating. I didn't know you can get a channel mask of a matrix just by doing a comparison with a scalar. The syntax now totally makes sense.

Comment: That explains. Thanks!

Comment: The place of that operators in sources is not very easy to find. It wrapped with macroses. There place some of them https://github.com/Itseez/opencv/blob/ddf82d0b154873510802ef75c53e628cd7b2cb13/modules/core/include/opencv2/core/operations.hpp#L226

Comment: You're welcome. And thanks for the interesting info. I will definitely use that. :P

Comment: @oklas I don't see the relational operators anywhere in that link. If you're using an IDE it ought to be able to find it

Comment: Yestarday I use onlinne github search with suppose macro definition instead of plain declaration. Yes IDE possible simpify search with its parse-features.. The decl and impl op the topic operators is near mat.hpp#L3367 matop.cpp#L997